# css menu alignment and word spacing issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have two small issues in CSS that I am unable to figure out. First is the ability to extend the area of the block on the drop down to fit the wording in properly. And secondly is the sub-menu, sub-menu placement. I have a fiddle setup here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05tpoy47/)

The only attribute from what I can tell is

```
display: inline-block;
```

This is the first issue: http://screencast.com/t/9GSbhMWe

And the second issue: http://screencast.com/t/TOAKiE5db

Could someone maybe assist if they could. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your stylesheet. Or you'd better find and edit the related properties directly.

```
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
}
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu li {
    display: block;
}
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu,
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu li a {
    width: auto;
}
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu li a {
    background: none;
}
```

To fix the 2nd issue, add this.

```
#nav .main-navigation .sub-menu .page_item_has_sub-menu {
    position: relative;
}
```